Displaying multiple returns from API JSON response
Attempting to display different API JSON responses on an HTML page instead of only one.  The API request comes back with three different responses but the html only will show the first one. How do I get this to display all responses no matter the number of returns?
When requesting the information from API, this is the JSON response I get.
{
  "success":true,
  "error":null,
  "response":[
    {
      "periods":[
        {
          "summary":{
            "temp":{
              "maxC":6,
              "maxF":44,
              "minC":3,
              "minF":37,
              "avgC":3.8,
              "avgF":38.8,
              "count":177,
              "qc":10
            },
            "dewpt":{
              "maxC":4,
              "maxF":39,
              "minC":1,
              "minF":33,
              "avgC":1.6,
              "avgF":34.9,
              "count":177,
              "qc":10
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "loc":{
        "long":-93.249759078026,
        "lat":44.977344633615
      }
    },
    {
      "periods":[
        {
          "summary":{
            "temp":{
              "maxC":7,
              "maxF":44,
              "minC":3,
              "minF":38,
              "avgC":4.2,
              "avgF":39.5,
              "count":159,
              "qc":10
            },
            "dewpt":{
              "maxC":4,
              "maxF":38,
              "minC":1,
              "minF":33,
              "avgC":1.5,
              "avgF":34.7,
              "count":159,
              "qc":10
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "loc":{
        "long":-93.248161315918,
        "lat":44.962871551514
      }
    },
    {
      "periods":[
        {
          "summary":{
            "temp":{
              "maxC":7,
              "maxF":44,
              "minC":3,
              "minF":37,
              "avgC":4.2,
              "avgF":39.6,
              "count":828,
              "qc":10
            },
            "dewpt":{
              "maxC":5,
              "maxF":41,
              "minC":2,
              "minF":35,
              "avgC":2.8,
              "avgF":37,
              "count":828,
              "qc":10
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "loc":{
        "long":-93.328,
        "lat":45.001
      }
    }
  ]
}

I am using this script on an html to show the results.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Weather Alerts</title>
    <script defer src="https://cdn.aerisapi.com/sdk/js/latest/aerisweather.min.js"></script>

    <style>
      #alerts .tempicon {
        position: absolute;
        top: 5px;
        left: 10px;
        width: 170px;
        height: 170px;
      }
      #alerts .temptext {
        position: absolute;
        top: 55px;
        left: 30px;
        color: #ffffff;
        font-size: 50px;
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        text-shadow: 2px 2px 5px black;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body topmargin="0" leftmargin="0">
    <div id="alerts"></div>

    <script>
      window.onload = () => {
        const target = document.getElementById("alerts");
        const aeris = new AerisWeather("[CLIENT_ID]", "[CLIENT_SECRET]");
        const request = aeris.api().endpoint("observations/summary").place("minneapolis,mn").from("today");
        request.get().then((result) => {
          const periods = result.data;
          if (periods) {
            console.log(periods);
            const html = `
            <img src="https://dakotaradar.org/newicons/temps/${periods[0].periods[0].summary.temp.maxF}.png" class="tempicon">
            <div class="temptext">${periods[0].periods[0].summary.temp.maxF}&#176;F</div>
            `;
            target.innerHTML = html;
          }
        });
      };
    </script>
  </body>
</html>


You're only seeing 1 result because you're only referring to the first result with [0].

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>API Responses</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="data-container"></div>

    <script>
        // فرض کنید این داده‌ها از API دریافت شده‌اند
        const jsonResponse = {
            "success": true,
            "error": null,
            "response": [
                {
                    "periods": [
                        {
                            "summary": {
                                "temp": {
                                    "maxC": 6,
                                    "maxF": 44,
                                    "minC": 3,
                                    "minF": 37,
                                    "avgC": 3.8,
                                    "avgF": 38.8,
                                    "count": 177,
                                    "qc": 10
                                },
                                "dewpt": {
                                    "maxC": 4,
                                    "maxF": 39,
                                    "minC": 1,
                                    "minF": 33,
                                    "avgC": 1.6,
                                    "avgF": 34.9,
                                    "count": 177,
                                    "qc": 10
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "loc": {
                        "long": -93.249759078026,
                        "lat": 44.977344633615
                    }
                },
                {
                    "periods": [
                        {
                            "summary": {
                                "temp": {
                                    "maxC": 7,
                                    "maxF": 44,
                                    "minC": 3,
                                    "minF": 38,
                                    "avgC": 4.2,
                                    "avgF": 39.5,
                                    "count": 159,
                                    "qc": 10
                                },
                                "dewpt": {
                                    "maxC": 4,
                                    "maxF": 38,
                                    "minC": 1,
                                    "minF": 33,
                                    "avgC": 1.5,
                                    "avgF": 34.7,
                                    "count": 159,
                                    "qc": 10
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "loc": {
                        "long": -93.248161315918,
                        "lat": 44.962871551514
                    }
                },
                {
                    "periods": [
                        {
                            "summary": {
                                "temp": {
                                    "maxC": 7,
                                    "maxF": 44,
                                    "minC": 3,
                                    "minF": 37,
                                    "avgC": 4.2,
                                    "avgF": 39.6,
                                    "count": 828,
                                    "qc": 10
                                },
                                "dewpt": {
                                    "maxC": 5,
                                    "maxF": 41,
                                    "minC": 2,
                                    "minF": 35,
                                    "avgC": 2.8,
                                    "avgF": 37,
                                    "count": 828,
                                    "qc": 10
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "loc": {
                        "long": -93.328,
                        "lat": 45.001
                    }
                }
            ]
        };

        // نمایش تمام داده‌ها
        const container = document.getElementById("data-container");

        jsonResponse.response.forEach(item => {
            const location = item.loc;
            const tempData = item.periods[0].summary.temp;

            const div = document.createElement("div");
            div.innerHTML = `
                <h3>Location: Latitude ${location.lat}, Longitude ${location.long}</h3>
                <p>Max Temp: ${tempData.maxC}°C (${tempData.maxF}°F)</p>
                <p>Min Temp: ${tempData.minC}°C (${tempData.minF}°F)</p>
                <p>Average Temp: ${tempData.avgC}°C (${tempData.avgF}°F)</p>
            `;
            container.appendChild(div);
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>


Don't just post code. Explain what the OP did wrong and how you fixed it. Also, your solution is almost identical to the other answer that was posted nearly 10 minutes before.


In this code, forEach is used to traverse the response array.
For each item, temperature and geographic location (latitude and longitude) information is extracted and added to the HTML.
The data is dynamically added to the divs and finally displayed on the page.

This code causes all JSON responses from the API to be displayed in HTML

That should be in the answer, not a comment.
